# ! Misplaced \omit. Longtable Error and Caption Misalign Extra alignment tab has been changed to \cr

Tags: longtable

The issue that I am having with the image of my longtable is that the caption is not centered and I have vertical lines that appear above my table. I have looked up other posts about my errors but non resolve the issue.

```
\begin{center}
\begin{longtable}{|c|c|c|}
\centering
\caption{Average Scalar Flux Groups 1 and 2 Test  C} \\
\hline
\rowcolor[gray]{0.85}\textbf{Average Scalar Flux Group 1} 
&\textbf{Average Scalar Flux Group 2} & \textbf{Distance} \\  
\hline
2.185692E-17    &   4.194769E-18        &       0.00 \\ \hline
-1.202652E-04   &   1.202652E-04        &       0.10\\ \hline
-2.405521E-04   &   2.405521E-04        &       0.20\\ \hline
-1.839872E-04   &   1.894445E-04        &       0.30\\ \hline
-1.295853E-04   &   1.403995E-04        &       0.40\\ \hline
-7.678566E-05   &   9.288239E-05        &       0.50\\ \hline
1.078685E-04    &   -1.078685E-04       &       22.30\\ \hline
0.000000E+00    &   0.000000E+00        &       22.40\\ \hline
\label{tlabel}
\end{longtable}
\end{Center}
```

This is what it looks like. The rest of the table looks fine. It is also cutting off a word in my header above the horizontal line at the top of the page on the left hand side. 
[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. Please post a MWE always

Answer (score 3):

You shouldn't enclose the `longtable` in a `center` environment, because the table will be centered by default. Also, `\label` should go besides the `\caption`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[margin=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{colortbl,longtable}
\usepackage{lipsum} % just for the example
\begin{document}

\lipsum[2]

\begin{longtable}{|c|c|c|}
\caption{Average Scalar Flux Groups 1 and 2 Test  C}
\label{tlabel} \\
\hline
\rowcolor[gray]{0.85}\textbf{Average Scalar Flux Group 1} 
&\textbf{Average Scalar Flux Group 2} & \textbf{Distance} \\  
\hline
2.185692E-17    &   4.194769E-18        &       0.00 \\ \hline
-1.202652E-04   &   1.202652E-04        &       0.10\\ \hline
-2.405521E-04   &   2.405521E-04        &       0.20\\ \hline
-1.839872E-04   &   1.894445E-04        &       0.30\\ \hline
-1.295853E-04   &   1.403995E-04        &       0.40\\ \hline
-7.678566E-05   &   9.288239E-05        &       0.50\\ \hline
1.078685E-04    &   -1.078685E-04       &       22.30\\ \hline
0.000000E+00    &   0.000000E+00        &       22.40\\ \hline
\end{longtable}

\lipsum[3]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Note that in the standard page setup for the `article` class the table is too wide, so it will stick in the right margin.

An even better result will be obtained with the help of the `siunitx` package that's able to format numbers in various ways. Note, in particular, that the hyphens in the preceding example should be minus signs.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[margin=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{colortbl,longtable,siunitx}
\usepackage{lipsum} % just for the example

\sisetup{
  output-exponent-marker=\ensuremath{\mathrm{E}},
  exponent-product={},
}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[2]

\begin{longtable}{
  |S[table-format=-1.6e-2]|
   S[table-format=-1.6e-2]|
   S[table-format=2.2]|
}
\caption{Average Scalar Flux Groups 1 and 2 Test  C}
\label{tlabel} \\
\hline
\rowcolor[gray]{0.85}\textbf{Average Scalar Flux Group 1}
&\textbf{Average Scalar Flux Group 2} & \textbf{Distance} \\  
\hline
2.185692E-17    &   4.194769E-18        &       0.00 \\ \hline
-1.202652E-04   &   1.202652E-04        &       0.10\\ \hline
-2.405521E-04   &   2.405521E-04        &       0.20\\ \hline
-1.839872E-04   &   1.894445E-04        &       0.30\\ \hline
-1.295853E-04   &   1.403995E-04        &       0.40\\ \hline
-7.678566E-05   &   9.288239E-05        &       0.50\\ \hline
1.078685E-04    &   -1.078685E-04       &       22.30\\ \hline
0.000000E+00    &   0.000000E+00        &       22.40\\ \hline
\end{longtable}

\lipsum[3]
\end{document}
```

[image]

---

You should also consider this possible enhancement, that avoids many problems both in readability and in horizontal spacing.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[margin=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{longtable,siunitx,booktabs}
\usepackage{lipsum} % just for the example

\sisetup{output-exponent-marker=\ensuremath{\mathrm{E}},exponent-product={}}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[2]

\begin{longtable}{
  S[table-format=-1.6e-2]
  S[table-format=-1.6e-2]
  S[table-format=2.2]
}
\caption{Average Scalar Flux Groups 1 and 2 Test  C}
\label{tlabel} \\
\toprule
\multicolumn{2}{c}{\textbf{Average Scalar Flux}} & {\textbf{Distance}} \\
\cmidrule{1-2}
{\textbf{Group 1}} & {\textbf{Group 2}} & \\
\midrule
 2.185692E-17 &  4.194769E-18 &  0.00 \\
-1.202652E-04 &  1.202652E-04 &  0.10 \\
-2.405521E-04 &  2.405521E-04 &  0.20 \\
-1.839872E-04 &  1.894445E-04 &  0.30 \\
-1.295853E-04 &  1.403995E-04 &  0.40 \\
-7.678566E-05 &  9.288239E-05 &  0.50 \\
 1.078685E-04 & -1.078685E-04 & 22.30 \\
 0.000000E+00 &  0.000000E+00 & 22.40 \\
\bottomrule
\end{longtable}

\lipsum[3]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: shouldn't those negative indicators in the table be minuses instead of hyphens?

Comment: @barbarabeeton Thanks for noticing. I uploaded a better version with `siunitx`